# Is there a way to check every input field for a missing value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to be able to display a ul tag with all the fields missing a value.

[image]

I want to check if the question, category, and gender are empty. As well as the consent is false.

Then I want to display a message like this

```
<h2>missing fields</h2>
<ul>
  <li>question</li/>
  <li>category</li/>
  <li>gender</li/>
  <li>consent</li/>
</ul>
```

Right now I have these functions:

```
let handleInputChange = event => {
 const target = event.target;
 const value = target.value;
 const name = target.name;

 setValues({
  ...values,
  [name]: value,
 });
}; 



let handleCheckboxChange = event => {
 const target = event.target;
 const value = target.checked;
 const name = target.name;

 setValues({
  ...values,
  [name]: value,
});
```

};

If for example the consent is set to true, then it should not appear when submitting the form

Comment: I think you are talking about this: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: but it doesn't tell me how to validate each input field

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work for you :-

```
<h2>missing fields</h2>
<ul>
   {Object.keys(values).filter(key=>key==='')).map(val=><li>val</li>)}
   {!values.consent && <li>consent</li>}
</ul>
```

Here we are getting all the `keys` of your `values` state in an array and filtering out only the ones which are equal to `''` and then `map` over them to display as `li` elements.
For consent we can explicitly handle it using `&&` i.e. only render this `li` element when `consent` is false.

Or you can also have one dedicated function like `renderMissingFields` where if you expect your fields to increase overtime you can write some custom logic like above but for this particular use case, above should suffice.

Also you can follow the rendering approach for other fields (for which I used `Object.keys`) same as `consent`.

In case you want all of them to fit the constraints as defined by you and only then render , you can do something like this :-

```
{!(question!=='' || gender!=='' || category!=='' || consent) &&
(<h2>missing fields</h2>
<ul>
 
  <li>question</li/>
  <li>category</li/>
  <li>gender</li/>
  <li>consent</li/>
</ul>
)
}
```

Comment: I think my question was bad. I want to click the submit button which then calls the handleSubmit function and from there I want to loop over the state object and tell the user which input is missing a value. Since all input is required to have a value. And eventually show them that list